# git status returning newline in script

Tags: git, bash, shell

I have the following script (which returns no errors in [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/)):

```
#! /bin/bash

function git_info {
  local git_status
  git_status="$(git status 2> /dev/null)"

  echo "$git_status" #returns new line
}
```

`git_status` is not getting set, or rather, it is getting a whitespace value. This function is getting run on every bash command. Below is what the console looks like.

```
local:~$

local:~$ git status
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

local:~$ cd projects/testdir/

local:~/p/testdir$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean

local:~/p/testdir$
```

Those empty lines right before each `local:~$` are where the function is echoing. It *should* be outputting what you can see when I run `git status`.

The code that runs this function on every command is in `.bash_profile` as follows:

```
source "$HOME/bin/testll.sh" # this is the file with git_info 

PS1="$(git_info)"           # prints current branch
PS1+="\[$COLOR_WHITE\]:\[$COLOR_BLUE\]\$(truncate)" # directory path
PS1+="\[$COLOR_WHITE\]\$\[$COLOR_RESET\] "   # '#' for root, else '$'
export PS1
```

Obviously this is supposed to be altering my prompt based on the git status, however I've narrowed the issue down to the git status acting up, and so in the interest of presenting an MCVE I've only shown that code. If you need to see more for whatever reason, I can add it to this question.

I know the `2>/dev/null` should be returning an empty string or null value or something on errors, so that is expected when `git status` outputs a `fatal: not a git repo...` message. But when I am in a git repo, this should not be interfering. So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: run the code with bash -x. This will allow you to better track the variables.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Raman Sailopal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7840440/raman-sailopal) recommending using `-x` to run the debugger, I found the issue is caused from this line in `.bash_profile`:

```
PS1="$(git_info)"
```

It should have been

```
PS1="\$(git_info)"
```

I don't know why escaping the dollar sign made a difference, but it caused the function to be run later in the process, which allowed `git status` to not cause errors.

As an aside, escaping the dollar sign also cause some parts of the echo string to be echoed literally. It is not shown in my question, but I was echoing colors and portions of that syntax was showing up, giving me `\]local:~$`. When I stripped those characters out of the string, it still worked, I don't know why escaping `$` allows this to be the case, but it is.

---

In short, escaping the function caused it to be called later in the process which (presumably) allowed the subshell context to be set correctly, thus allowing `git status` to not error and dump the output into `/dev/null`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine.

But you are using `echo` which always adds a newline to what it is echoing. Do avoid this behaviour, just use `-n` parameter.

```
echo -n "$git_status"
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you wanted to capture stderr also

```
git_status="$(git status 2>&1)"
```

instead of

```
git_status="$(git status 2> /dev/null)"
```

and without redirection stderr will be displayed directly in the tty (fd2 inherited from parent process):

```
git_status="$(git status)"
```